# Volume of irregular piece of pie

Tags: c++, math, geometry

Imagine that we cut a piece of pie with known fixed height (H). We cut it in such a way that the upper arc has angle A1 and the bottom arc has angle A2. However, we also know that the upper arc has two radii (R1 and R2) and the bottom arc has two different radii (R3 and R4). These four radii are not connected anyhow to each other (might be elliptic axis, but might be total random).
[image]
Technically, if not thinking about pies, we have two polygons (with the same number of points), with mass centers a bit different from each other. Taking two points from the upper polygon, we assume they form a local elliptic arc with two radii and angle A1. (The other arc from the same polygon will most likely have different radii values and angle).
We can take two points from the lower polygon which will correspond to the two points of the upper polygon (typically, using index values) and form the lower local elliptic arc with another angle and radii values.

Thus the question is how to calculate the volume of this piece? Again, two upper radii (R1 and R2), two bottom radii (R3 and R4), fixed height (H) and two angles (A1 and A2). Note: the centers of the upper and bottom parts (essentially, polygons) might be different.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: An image that illustrates what you are describing in words would make it easier to follow what you are saying.

Comment: belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think the problem is ill-posed. What's the height H? Is that the length of the edge of the slice, or the height of the pie? Unless the edge runs perfectly vertical, its length will differ from the height of the pie. And given that R1-R4 are unrelated, we can't assume it's vertical.

Comment: @kennytm: It's a bit too simple there. The volume is just ∫A(h)dh where A(h) is the area of the slice at height h.

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. If the edge of the pie is vertical, the cuts form planes and therefore the sides are perfect rectangles. That means R1==R3 and R2==R4. The problem _is_ ill-defined.

Comment: ok, I assumed something would not be perfectly specified :) All the edges are not vertical due to the difference of radii and the mass centers. Thus the height value needs more explanation... hold on. Yeah, the both polygons are lying in two parallel planes and the height value is the distance between these two planes

Comment: We can also say that all the points in the upper polygon have constant z coordinate value (Z1) and the point in the lower polygon have Z2

Answer (score 0):

This approximation might help (assuming A1, A2 to be given in radians):

- area of top "sector" A_top ~ (R1 + R2) * A1 / 4
- area of bottom "sector" A_bot ~ (R3 + R4) * A2 / 4
- volume of piece of pie V ~ (A_top + A_bot) * H / 2